# Override the CheckPasswordAsync when user logs in with Identity 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I implemented the authentication with ASP.NET Core Identity 2.0 in an existing App. As I use my own database schema and classes, I use my own User class and I had to create a custom UserStore. 
The problem is when I created the users, I hashed their password not with the same method which is use in Identity and the login failed when this function is called :

```cs
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Login, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```

I have seen on different post that you need to override the CheckPasswordAsync() function to add your own way to check if the passwords are similar. However, I tried to implement it but it is no a success...

CustomUserManager:

```cs
public class CustomUserManager<TUser> : UserManager<TUser> where TUser : class
{
    public CustomUserManager(IUserStore<TUser> store, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
IPasswordHasher<TUser> passwordHasher, IEnumerable<IUserValidator<TUser>> userValidators,
IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<TUser>> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer,
IdentityErrorDescriber errors, IServiceProvider services, ILogger<UserManager<TUser>> logger) : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger)
    {
    }

    public override Task<bool> CheckPasswordAsync(TUser user, string password)
    {
        return base.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password);
    }
}
```

AccountController constructor :

```cs
public AccountController(
        CustomUserManager<User> userManager,
        SignInManager<User> signInManager,
        ILogger<AccountController> logger)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }
```

I even tried to Add the scope in the services configuration:

```cs
services.AddIdentity<User, ProfileUser>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
services.AddTransient<IUserStore<User>, UserIdentity>();
services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<ProfileUser>, ProfileIdentity>();
services.AddScoped< UserManager<User>, CustomUserManager>();
```

But it doesn't work. When I launch the App and try to access to the login page, I get an error:

```cs
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'CustomUserManager`1[Maquetteur.Entities.User]' while attempting to activate 'Maquetteur.Web.AccountController'.
```

With the default UserManager I can access to the login Page but the login function fails. With the custom UserManager I cannot access to the login page.

Do you have an idea what I'm doing wrong ? Or maybe there is an other way to implement our own way to check if passwords are similar when the user logs in ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were heading in the right direction when you added this line:

```
services.AddScoped<UserManager<User>, CustomUserManager>();
```

This line essentially says: *If I ask for a `UserManager<User>`, please give me a `CustomUserManager`* instead. However, that's not exactly what you intended here. Instead, you wanted to say: *If I ask for a `CustomUserManager`, please just give me a `CustomUserManager`*.

It's actually quite easy to fix - You can just register it when you add the Identity services. e.g.:

```
services
    .AddIdentity<User, ProfileUser>()
    .AddUserManager<CustomUserManager<User>>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Note: There are also additional extensions for registering your custom `IUserStore` and `IRoleStore` implementations.

Comment: Shouldn't the controller constructor also be changed to `UserManager<User>`?

Comment: @Brad It *can* be changed, but it's not required. `AddUserManager<T>` [registers  both](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core/IdentityBuilder.cs#L155).